# Will the loss decrease if i fit the model once again or will it reset to initial loss?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

```py
    for iteration in range(NUM_ITERATIONS):
        print()
        print("="*50)
        print("Iteration:",iteration)
        model.fit(X,y,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,epochs=NUM_EPOCH_ITERATION)
        rand=np.random.randint(len(x_labels))
        test="vikas n s "
        print(test,end="")

        for i in range(NUM_PREDICTION_PER_EPOCH):
            Xtest=np.zeros((1,sqlen,nb_chars),dtype=np.bool)
            for i,ch in enumerate(test):
                Xtest[0,i,char2index[ch]]=1
            pred=model.predict(Xtest)
            temp=pred
            pred=pred[0]
            ypredict=index2char[np.argmax(pred)]
            print(ypredict,end="")
            test=test[1:]+ypredict
```

In this code,at every iteration I'm fitting the model.
My assumption is that as I'm fitting the model again the loss should be reset to original loss or something close to that.But what I'm finding is that the loss continues.
ie:
if the initial loss is 4
and after all the epoch in 1st iteration loss drops to 2.
Now when i once again fit the model in the next iteration i expect the loss to start from 4.Instead it continues from 2.
Why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like the model is never reset in that code. So no, it should not show loss values similar to those at the beginning of the training process.

Comment: @E_net4  how to reset a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Keras `model.fit` method does exactly that, i.e. starts training from whatever state the model has been by then; hence, if the model has already undergone some training from a previous session/iteration, the new `fit` starts from that point indeed.

If you want to have a new fitting session for each iteration (i.e. "resetting" your model), you should wrap your model building in a convenience function, and call this function in each iteration before `model.fit` (or of course simply include the whole model building code in each iteration...).

Comment: can u modify the above to reset?